# Is good practice create a controller for auto-complete filters?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, autocomplete

I'm a newbie in asp.net mvc.

I need to create a 'auto-complete tag search' functionality like stackoverflow. My intent is to create a controller with JsonResult to get a filtered tag to auto-complete the input-text element. This is a good practice? If yes, any recommendations for something I need to avoid?

Thanks in advance.

PS.: Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution suggested by kekekela can be used even if there are multiple filter parameters, no need to create multiple actions unless the result set is of different type. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public JsonResult FilterTasks(int maxResults, string users = "", string tags = "", string categories = "")
    {
        List<int> userIdList = MyHelper.GetIntList(users);
        List<string> tagNameList = MyHelper.GetStringList(tags);
        List<string> categoryIdList = MyHelper.GetStringList(categories);
        var tasks = from task in projectsEntities.Tasks select task;
        if (userIdList.Count >  0)
            tasks = tasks.Where(task => userIdList.Contains(task.UserId));
        if (tagNameList.Count > 0)
            tasks = tasks.Where(task => tagNameList.Contains(task.TagName));
        if (categoryIdList.Count > 0)
            tasks = tasks.Where(task => categoryIdList.Contains(task.CategoryId));
        var topTasks = tasks.Take(maxResults).ToArray();
        return Json(topTasks);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a controller action then yes, this is how I've done it.  You could add a new controller but typically I've just added a method to an existing controller where it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I need many filters? Will be a good practice create a controller for all my filters? Ex.: /filter/tags/,/filter/users , /filter/categories etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a reason to bypass controllers at all! They ensure your calls follow a pattern. I've never gone back to straight php, asp, or jsp pages since I've started using MVC packages, keeps the code so nice and separated according to concerns.